# How to use Row and RowSpam in XAML Screens

Tags: uwp-xaml

The Code I will Used
The Row and rowspan is using this page but i will expected row span in the the value start in Zero Index and End in rowspan="3"

```
<Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Source="/Resources//Others/5.png" Margin="2 2 0 0" Stretch="Fill"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="65*"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="68*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="2" Source="/Resources//Others/6.png" Stretch="UniformToFill" Margin="0,2,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"/>
            </Grid>
            <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="3" Source="/Resources//Others/6.png" Margin="2 2 0 0" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
```

The Output Screen Like This

[image: Output Screen]

But I expected this

[image: Expected Screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to use Row and RowSpam in XAML Screens

For understanding this, you could create 3 columns 3 rows grid like the following.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

If your want to occupy two behind whole columns. you need set `RowSpan` as 3, then set `Column` that you want start.

```
<Rectangle Fill="LightCyan" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
<Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2"/>
```

[image]

The following is complete xaml code.

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Rectangle Fill="Red" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="Gray" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="BlueViolet" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"/>


    <Rectangle Fill="LightCyan" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <Rectangle Fill="LightGreen" Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="2"/>

</Grid>
```

Comment: That is a not a Color Rectangle Tab..That is a Image File.I used User Convenient I will load a tab Image like a rectangle tab  ...

Comment: @NaveenS The above is just an example that explain RowSpan, you could replace Rectangle with other control.

Comment: All Right .The Responsive in UWP not Proper in this Page View

Comment: Could you share a mini sample that I could help edit the xaml directly?

Comment: No Need.The above Sample code given by You is working Fine in WPF 8' Tab Size also.....Thanks